# Why won't my API update the values of my form?

Tags: javascript, angular, api, ngx-bootstrap, angular-ngselect

I'm trying to update the attributes of objects which can be observed using a form. I am able to call the API to create new objects and map the values for each attribute to the form's inputs so that the form is prepopulated once I click on the object after its creation.

The intended functionality for the modification is to also prepopulate the form's inputs with the updated data once I click on the object but right now the API call does not work and my Object is not being updated.

Here is the code for my form:

```
categoryForm = new FormGroup<CategoryForm>({
        enTitle: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true }),
        frTitle: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true }),
        enDesc: new FormControl(''),
        frDesc: new FormControl(''),
        type: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true }),
        slug: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true }),
        categories: new FormControl([]),
        subcategories: new FormControl([])
    });
```

Here is the code for the function that adds a new object that works just fine:

```
confirmAddCategory() {
        let categoriesToAdd = [];
        this.categoryForm.controls.categories.value.forEach((category: Category) => {
            categoriesToAdd.push(category.id)
        }) 
        // this.categoryForm.controls.categories.value.forEach((category: Category) => categoriesToAdd.push((category.id as string)));
        let subcategoriesToAdd = [];
        this.categoryForm.controls.subcategories.value.forEach((category: Category) => {
            subcategoriesToAdd.push(category.id)
        })
        let category: INewCategory = {
            title: {
                en: this.categoryForm.controls.enTitle.value,
                fr: this.categoryForm.controls.frTitle.value
            },
            description: {
                en: this.categoryForm.controls.enDesc.value,
                fr: this.categoryForm.controls.frDesc.value
            },
            slug: this.categoryForm.controls.slug.value,
            type: this.categoryForm.controls.type.value,
            //categories: this.newCategory.controls.categories,
            categories: categoriesToAdd,
            subcategories: subcategoriesToAdd
        }

        this.categoryForm.controls.categories.setValue(categoriesToAdd)
        this.categoryForm.controls.subcategories.setValue(subcategoriesToAdd)

        console.log(category)
        this.categoryService.addCategory(category).subscribe({
            next: (response: any) => {
                this.ngxSmartModalService.close('addCategoryModal')
            }
        })
    }
```

Here is the code for the modify function that causes a 400 error followed by a "Missing Input" prompt:

```
confirmModifyCategory() {
        let categoriesToModify = [];
        this.categoryForm.controls.categories.value.forEach((category: Category) => {
            categoriesToModify.push(category.id)
        })
        let subcategoriesToModify = [];
        this.categoryForm.controls.subcategories.value.forEach((category: Category) => {
            subcategoriesToModify.push(category.id)
        })
        let category: ICategoryModification = {
            title: {
                en: this.categoryForm.controls.enTitle.value,
                fr: this.categoryForm.controls.frTitle.value
            },
            description: {
                en: this.categoryForm.controls.enDesc.value,
                fr: this.categoryForm.controls.frDesc.value
            },
            slug: this.categoryForm.controls.slug.value,
            type: this.categoryForm.controls.type.value,

            categories: categoriesToModify,
            subcategories: subcategoriesToModify
        }

        console.log(category)
        this.categoryService.editCategory(category, category.slug).subscribe({
            next: (response: any) => {
                this.ngxSmartModalService.close('categoryModal')
            }
        })
    }
```

Here is the code demonstrating the functionality of the API call functions:

```
export class CategoryService {

    constructor(private baseService: BaseService) { }

    addCategory(category: INewCategory){
        return this.baseService.create('categories', category)
    }

    editCategory(category: ICategoryModification, slug: string){
        return this.baseService.patch('categories/' + slug, category)
    }

}
```

How can I fix the modify function so that it correctly updates the Object and form's values upon clicking the confirm button?

Comment: Error 400 states that your request payload is invalid. You need to debug in the backend part

Comment: Is there any additional info in call response which shows why the input is invalid. You are missing some value in the payload.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.